# Extended BNF of BBCode

Tags: bbcode, bnf, ebnf

There is a [BBCode reference site](https://www.bbcode.org/). But is there any existed [Backus normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) of [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)?

Comment: The "reference site" is actually very old. Modern BBCode variants move forward along with the rest of the world and might include "mentions", "headers", "spacers", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote one for my [personal project](https://github.com/shiningdracon/BBCode-Swift):

```
 <document> ::= <element> | <document> <element>
 <element> ::= <tag> | <content>
 <tag> ::= <opening_tag_1> | <opening_tag> <content> <closing_tag>
 <opening_tag> ::= <opening_tag_1> | <opening_tag_2>
 <opening_tag_1> ::= <tag_prefix> <tag_end>
 <opening_tag_2> ::= <tag_prefix> '=' <attr> <tag_end>
 <tag_prefix> ::= <tag_start> <tag_name>
 <tag_start> ::= '['
 <tag_end> ::= ']'
 <attr> ::= <character> | <attr> <character>
 <closing_tag> ::= <tag_start> '/' <tag_name> <tag_end>
 <tag_name> ::= <character_non-key> | <tag_name> <character_non-key_2>
 <content> ::= <character> | <content> <character>
 <character> ::= unicode
 <character_non-key> ::= unicode not including '[', '=', ']', '/'
 <character_non-key_2> ::= <character_non-key> | '/'
```